# What can I use as a replacement for ricotta or cottage cheese in a lasagna?

Tags: substitutions, cheese, pasta, lasagna

I really cannot take the texture of ricotta or cottage cheese in food, to the point where I will gag when it is in my mouth.

However, most of the recipes I have seen for lasagna involve using one or the other. Is there something I can use as a replacement that will do the same sort of cheese thing that they do, without the weird texture?

Answer (score 26):

I've never used ricotta or any soft cheese on my lasagne - I wonder if it is an Italian *American* convention. I use bechamel sauce, mozarella and parmesan, and it works very well.

Comment: I agree, I've never seen ricotta in an Italian lasagne. Bechamel is a much better option anyway.

Comment: Ricotta in lasagna is very much Italian Italian. Just not in every region.

Comment: I have seen cheese lasagna where the cheese replaces the bechamel, touted as "quick lasagna" because you don't cook the sauce. I think I've mostly seen it with mascarpone though.

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Zmtmzj6Klj0 The video I've attached shows gordon Ramsay making a lasagna with what looks like a bechamel sauce. Can you watch it and confirm?

Comment: if I had the need to go "quick", instead of subbing ingredients I suggest just buying pre made béchamel.

Answer (score 6):

Use any fresh cheese like fior di latte, bocconcini, or fresh mozzarella with a little bit of fresh parmesan.

It depends on the region, some people use non cheese sauces like béchamel and even some use orange cheddar.

If you like a fresh and subtle tasting lasagna without the gritty texture of ricotta, a nice mix of fior di latte and fresh mozzarella along with thin fresh lasagna strips make a lovely dish.

Answer (score 5):

For one nondairy option you can use a puree of cooked garbanzo beans (chickpeas), lemon juice, salt, a bit of cornstarch, and garlic if desired.  I like this for lasagnas as it doesn't overpower the dish with a cheesy flavor and lets the vegetable flavors really come through.

Another option is to soak cashews for a few hours, then puree them with lemon juice and salt, adding water as needed.

Answer (score 4):

Cream Cheese is a great substitute. I have a friend with similar distaste to cottage cheese so we just use cream cheese, cheddar and mozzarella.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with the texture issue.  I had luck this week using real - not light - sour cream instead of ricotta.  I combined provolone, mozzarella and the sour cream togther before adding the additional ingredients.

Answer (score 3):

I read through all the answers because I was out of my two favorites for lasagna -- ricotta and cauliflower. People interested in a great alternative to ricotta and cottage cheese, might try steamed, pureed cauliflower with some cream cheese stirred in while hot. I like this as "faux mashed potatoes" but it works well in lasagna, especially with slides of zucchini and yellow squash which are a good substitute for a noodle layer, or sauteed portabella, or broiled/grilled slices of eggplant. Bon appetit!

Answer (score 2):

Crumbled firm tofu with some seasonings is a commonly used layer in vegan lasagna recipes.

Comment: Talk about texture problems, though. If you think ricotta has an unpleasant texture, just try to swallow some crumbled tofu.

Comment: Well it does have less of the airy, chewy, and light (think that's how you'd wine-politely describe styrofoam :) texture some cottage cheeses have...

Comment: For non-vegans, mixing silken tofu with some egg is decent.

Answer (score 2):

Also try sieving or blending the cottage cheese first, if you don't like the texture but don't mind its subtle flavour. It changes the texture totally, and my husband will happily eat it in pasta dishes, even though he doesn't like the texture usually.

Answer (score 2):

My mother mixes the cottage cheese into the meat & sauce. I HATE cottage cheese but it's not bad this way bc you dont get a thick layer. She mixes it while the meat sauce is still on the stove so it melts for the most part. I don't eat lasagna out bc I can't stand the layer of ricotta or cottage cheese.

Comment: This does actually provide an answer to the question. The OP asked for a substitution, but their actual issue was the *texture* of the cheese, and this answer provides a way to avoid that texture.

Answer (score 1):

I have been experimenting with a mushroom, egg and crouton mix instead of ricotta still polishing the recipe but I like it.  I have even made a breakfast lasagna with scrambled eggs, hashbrowns, salsa, and sausage, and cheese of course.

Answer (score 1):

I make a white sauce using the mozzarella cheese.  Since I use non-fat milk to make the sauce, it cuts down on calories.  This has always worked very well in my lasagna recipe.

Answer (score 1):

I substitute small curd cottage cheese for the ricotta cheese and i mash any large curds... i seriously dislike ricotta and cottage cheese and this way (whey) i don't notice it being in there. Also, I use 1/2 amount in recipe and this camouflages the ingredient as well. Hope this suggestion helps.