# Cheese substitution in casserole recipe

Tags: cheese

The recipe calls for:

- 200 g (each): broccoli and cauliflower.
- 200 g: cottage cheese.
- 100 mL: water.
- 1/2 tsp (each): nutmeg and thyme.
- Salt & pepper.
- 30 g: Parmesan cheese.
- Coconut oil.

So in the directions, you start chopping vegetables. Then you make the **creamy sauce**: mixing cottage cheese, water, nutmeg, thyme, salt and pepper. After that you pour this cream in the casserole with vegetables and sprinkle Parmesan cheese. Finally you just bake.

What cheese, or other ingredient, can I use instead of cottage? **It can be anything but cottage**. I'm looking for one as high in protein as cottage (so, would yogurt work?, but that's more nutrition-related, so a **substitution for the texture and flavor** would be the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: Are you looking for a non dairy, non cheese substitute? Or just anything that isn't _cottage_ cheese?

Comment: Anything that isn't cottage.

Comment: Is the sauce heated before baking or mixed cold?

Comment: @Stephie It's mixed **and** baked: you make the sauce (cottage, water and species), then mix it with the veggies and then bake.

Answer (score 2):

As ricotta is often substituted in lasagna with cottage cheese, it seems like you should be able to do the reverse in this recipe.

Other options mentioned in [this similar question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/41403/what-can-i-use-as-a-replacement-for-ricotta-or-cottage-cheese-in-a-lasagna) include sour cream and cream cheese.

Comment: Will try it tomorrow!